# Dropbox API help

Tags: objective-c, oauth, dropbox

I have downloaded the Objective-C api from [here](http://bitbucket.org/dropboxapi/dropbox-client-objc) (the one on their site is for iOS) however I am getting an "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string:" error when I try to upload a file.  I can login just fine, but it's just uploading that doesn't work.  From looking around it seems to be an oauth problem.  How can I fix it or where is there a wrapper that works with osx out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

The DropboxSDK repository you referred to looks old. You should get the release SDK from https://www.dropbox.com/developers/releases

Comment: that one is pretty much for iOS, it doesn't compile nicely for OSX, sure it will work, but it'll take some doin' besides, this is a "just for me" app

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 

Login is fine, but upload generated invalid signature error.

I was calling:

```
[self.restClient uploadFile:filename toPath:nil fromPath:fromPath];
```

In my case I have to always specify `toPath(@"")` attribute even if I specify root directory.